# Django signals doesnt save models with custom params

Tags: python, django

I have a custom user model **CustomUser** and related models **Employee** with Foreignkey field to user.

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    """Employee information."""
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField("first name", max_length=32, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField("last name", max_length=32, blank=True)
```

I try to create **Employee** instance after user registration using *post_save* signals with fields *first_name* and *last_name* imported from my user model fields.

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=CustomUser)
def create_or_update_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        if instance.first_name and instance.last_name:
            employee = Employee.objects.create(user=instance, first_name=instance.cleaned_data['first_name'], last_name=instance.clened_data['last_name'] )
        else:
            employee = Employee.objects.create(user=instance)
```

But always created model with blank field. What is the reason for this and what needs to be changed?

p.s. I need the same filds at both models for some reason.

Comment: "For some reason" - for *what* reason? You can always get the values from the related user, so what's the point?

Comment: @DanielRoseman A part of the written code uses fields from Employee model. And sometimes the same fields from both models have various values.